# Conditional formatting for arrival times vs scheduled times w/ tolerance

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm creating a report that will have to show the actual time of arrival versus what was scheduled, and I'm trying to figure out a way to have it working properly. Obviously there are different scheduled times of arrival and the formatting should also take into consideration the following:

- Showing one color if the person is early or up to 59 seconds after the scheduled time: e.g. scheduled at 8:00:00 it should still show as compliant be it that the person arrives at 7:55:00 or that arrives at 8:00:45
- Showing another color if the person arrives any moment from exactly one minute later to five minutes later: e.g. scheduled at 7:00:00 and the person arrives any time between 07:01:00 and 07:05:00
- Showing another color if the person arrives any moment from five minutes one second onwards: e.g. scheduled at 9:00:00 and arrives at 09:05:01
- Scheduled times of arrival can be changed on a day's notice, therefore it should ideally be checking against it "constantly", here you can find a sketch of what I mean

[image]

I've been bashing my head on this for a while but I cannot come up with anything that actually works, it's just a mess of what looks almost random formatting taking place.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below screenshot samples for the same

Select One Cell That Where do you want to apply conditional format and start below method.

**Creating New Rule**

[image]

**Select "Format only cells that contain" option.**

[image]

**Applying 1st Condition**

[image]

**Applying 2nd Condition**

[image]

**Applying 3rd Condition**

[image]

**Cross Check The Order and Cell Reference**

[image]

**Note:**

In  the above conditional format formula i have taken formula reference from **Scheduled Timing**  `=$F4` and added some values to adjust the timings as per your requirements. so please review it properly.
And use [**"$"**](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/11/25/relative-absolute-reference-excel/) to freezing the cell Row or column properly.

For applying it in all Cells use **`Format Painter`** and then apply.

Follow the same steps in your work book and get it success.

**To Know more about conditional formatting with formulas: [Click Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/comment-page-6/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, but somehow it's still not working and it seems to only apply whatever is set first regardless of what appears to be the actual value in the cell. It is driving me nuts to be fair.

https://imgur.com/Rw2TdC3

And trying to use the format painter yields even poorer results because it simply copies and pastes whatever color the cell has been transformed to.

Comment: Hey Dear Luca, it sounds like you were not Changing cell reference with "$"simple reason my Note: completely to understand about this. in the _"$"_ & Click here i have hidden a Hyperlink  click and review it. It might help you out. Still You have not understood let me know, somehow i will identify easy way to get it success.

Comment: Hi Regiz, if you go by the screenshot I attached in my previous comment, I indeed changed the cell reference but it's still not working at all, here's another screenshot with more details about the formula itself, and FYI the formatting applies to the range =$D$3:$D$14

https://imgur.com/lHimJp8

Comment: @Scott Craner needs you help on this Problem. Any Idea about this. This Screenshot seems like with formulas, is conditional formatting won't work out in formulas cells? please help to get exact solution.